# What is the equivalent My Function code in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write below VB.net code to C#. What is best equivalent code in C#:

```
Private Sub AllControlDesign2(ByRef TB As Control)
    If TB.GetType Is GetType(StatusStrip) Then
        CType(TB, TextBox).ReadOnly = True
        TB.BackColor = stFromBackColour
        TB.ForeColor = Color.Gray
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service, mate, you need something like RentACoder. Why don't you try putting some effort into it first, then we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: So if `TB` is a `StatusStrip`, you convert it to a `TextBox`? How can that do anything other than raise an `InvalidCastException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the equivellant, copied from [DeveloperFusion.com](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=16e2f010-5732-4dca-8d01-dbdda89bd015)

```
private void AllControlDesign2(ref Control TB)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(TB.GetType, typeof(StatusStrip))) {
        ((TextBox)TB).ReadOnly = true;
        TB.BackColor = stFromBackColour;
        TB.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, that was a real timing :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
private void AllControlDesign2(Control tb) {
    var textBox = tb as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null) {
        textBox.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox.BackColor = stFromBackColour;
        textBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void AllControlDesign2(ref Control TB)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(TB.GetType, typeof(StatusStrip))) {
        ((TextBox)TB).ReadOnly = true;
        TB.BackColor = stFromBackColour;
        TB.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

converted using [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/).

Comment: GetType is not a property, for starters.